# Could Congress pass a law restricting their own ability to pass laws?

Tags: united-states, congress

Suppose the First Amendment had never been ratified. Could Congress pass a bill with the same wording, but also prohibiting then from repealing it?

Comment: I am assuming implicitly that this question assumes that this would be done without complying with the requirements for a constitutional amendment.

Comment: @ohwilleke yes, just a normal bill passed by Congress other than its "unrepealable" clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, but that wouldn’t stop the same or a future Congress from repealing it

That is, there’s no rule that says the law can’t contain such a prohibition, just that it would be ineffective. What Congress does, Congress can undo.

Comment: They can't make a rock so heavy they can't lift it, etc... :)

Comment: Indeed, there are laws about the Congressional budget process that have just that character.

Comment: What if they amended the Senate or House rules to prohibit bills repealing that law or the section in the rules prohibiting repealing the law?

Comment: Or make it impossibly difficult, e.g. debate must continue for at least ten years

Comment: @Someone Not hypothetical, of course. This can be disregarded using the "nuclear option." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option

Comment: @Someone sure, but then they can vote to change the rules.

Comment: @DaleM even if the rules say they can't (or can only in theory) vote to change that part of the rules? The nuclear option would work in the Senate, but AFAIK it isn't available in the House.

Comment: @Someone if a chamber decided to throw out all the rules and make new ones, there is no one but themselves who can decide if that is OK or not. The internal operations of each chamber are not justiciable.

Comment: @DaleM oh, okay, that makes sense. So changing the rules in a way that breaks pre-existing rules is technically illegal, but unreviewable?

Comment: @Someone not exactly. There are no laws on how a chamber conducts the business that the Constitution entrusts to them. Therefore, so long as they do is, how they do it is not a legal question. If a chamber decided that every bill would be decided by the chair tossing a coin, that’s fine. Elected officials are answerable at the ballot box, not the courthouse.

Comment: @DaleM so the houses of Congress basically have absolute discretion as to whether or not to follow their rules?

Comment: @Someone they make ‘em, they can break ‘em

Comment: @Someone U.S. Const. Art. I, Section 5, Clause 2: "**Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings**, punish its Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two thirds, expel a Member."

Answer (score -1):

A law can never have the force of the Constitution, since a law can always be overturned.  A Constitutional Ammendment can also be overturned, but via a specific method outside of Congress alone.  Also, since the Constitution has a higher standing than laws, it is more likely to be over-ridden by other Constitutional issues.  The Constitution tends to come into conflict with itself fairly often, it is the balancing of different portions that makes Constitutional Law difficult.  For example, a law about freedom to practice religion would not have as much weight as a constitutional statement about it.